# ADO EF data manipulation methodology

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, generics

I was hoping someone could point me in the direction of refactoring some of my methods to accept generic types.

I have a Service that speaks with many different tables in my database. The majority of the tables are of the same format. The service performs the same basic operations on all of the tables, GetAll, Save, Delete. Since the operation is the same I was looking for a way to create a core library of actions.

This is an example of my save function, the only difference between this and that of the other tables is the data. So here its ClientData, on the next one its GroupData ect...

```
internal static void SaveClient(ClientData clientData)
        {
            using (CFOEntityModelContainer database = new CFOEntityModelContainer())
            {
                if (!IsClientValid(clientData.Id))
                {
                    database.Clients.AddObject(ConvertClientDataToClient(clientData));
                    database.SaveChanges();
                }
                else
                {
                    Client client = database.Clients.First(
                        c => c.Id == clientData.Id);

                    client.Name = clientData.Name;

                    database.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you expect to make it generic if your method contains type specific operations? Do you always have XXX entity and XXXData class where XXX entity contains `Id` and `Name` and XXXData class contains `Name` and `Id`? If not your generic save would be just template accepting delegates to specific method = no simplification. If yes you can do something like:

First prepare interface used in generic methods:

```
public interface IData
{
    int Id { get; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now implement that interface on your entity and data classes and create generic method:

```
internal static void Save<TEntity, TData>(TData data)
    where TEntity : class, IData
    where TData : class, IData
{
    using (CFOEntityModelContainer database = new CFOEntityModelContainer())
    {
        ObjectSet<TEntity> set = database.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();

        // Here you have specific method - can you make it generic?
        // If not it must be another parameter (delegate) passed to Save method
        if (!IsValid(data.Id))  
        {
            // Convert is another specific method which must be generalize
            // This time it can be probably solved by overriding conversion
            // operator on each data implementation
            set.AddObject(Convert(data));
        }
        else
        {
            // Another specific logic - can you make it generic?
            // If not it must be passed as delegate
            TEntity entity = set.First(e => e.Id == data.Id);
            entity.Name = data.Name;
        }

        database.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

You can call this method like:

```
Save<Client, ClientData>(data);
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight, I will set to working on this right away